# Spring Boot REST architecture

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, model-view-controller

Lately i've been developing a Spring boot application with Angular 5 frontend and i got a little confused about the architecture of it. I was taught to write repositories, services and controllers in spring and to follow the MVC pattern. I started to write the documentation for the app and im trying to describe the arhitecture. So as i think View is the Angular app, C consists of the controller classes, and i described the third layer as buisniss logic which consists of the entity and service classes. But what is the Model really? Did i manage to follow the MVC pattern? In addition i have a controlleradvice, exception classes and security classes that make the authentication and authorization using jwts, but i guess these classes totally stay out from the MVC.

I've searched for the explanation but didnt seem to find it. Could someone please explain this to me? Thank you!

UPDATE

So basically what i dont understand is how the spring classes + angular meet the requirements of the MVC pattern

For example this is one of the first diagrams on the internet when you search for spring layers but as i see these are different from MVC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtkv7.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is it only about a clean definition for MVC? That should be available on so many pages in the internet.....

Comment: It is not feasible trying to extend the MVC pattern across Spring _and_ Angular. You should consider both Angular and Spring as an application of their own, both able to implement MVC patterns. When having Angular in the front-end, Spring typically doesn't do anything view-related, so there is neither a Controller nor a View. It provides the Model, e.g. JSON via a Rest-Interface, which is consumed by the Angular's service layer and propagated to the _Components_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, both your backend with Spring boot and your frontend with Angular can be seen as different applications, each following the Model-View-Controller design pattern.

You also posted a screenshot of the [three-tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). This type of architecture only tells you about how to structure your code. Typically, the MVC-part of your application is within the **presentation layer** (in your screenshot it's called the web layer).

So, if you would look at your backend application, you can identify the following parts:

- **Data tier**/Repository layer: Repositories
- **Business tier**/Service layer: Services
- **Presentation tier**/Web layer: Model-View-Controller + Dispatcher

  - **Model**: Whatever you expose within your services (could be DTOs)
  - **View**: JSON structure/mapping
  - **Controller**: Spring controllers

And for your frontend you could identify them as well:

- **Data tier**: HTTP calls
- **Business tier**: Angular services
- **Presentation tier**: Components + Router

  - **Model**: Whatever you expose within your services (probably a similar structure as the one you expose in your backend)
  - **View**: Templates
  - **Controller**: Components

[image: Overview]

This is a bit oversimplified though, and probably not something everyone will agree with.

Comment: i thought that angular uses a CBA architecture, which is different from MVC, since a CBA separates between the Model view & controller vertically using data bindings and events.

Comment: @YassineBenHamida Certainly there are a few differences in approach, but broadly seen, Spring MVC also works with events (incoming HTTP requests) and bindings (it binds the data to a JSON structure). The key-difference is that MVC is all about separating the model-view-controller, while a CBA is more about separating by component, and less about separating the model, view and the controller/... .

Comment: But either way, the most important thing I'm trying to tell in my answer is that you shouldn't see your entire Angular application as a part of the MVC of your backend. They're individual applications with separate patterns to follow.

Comment: that's true, but when speaking about tiers in the image you provided, what do you exactly mean, because the presentation tier or" layer" is angular itself, the business tier is the spring boot backend and the data tier is the database server or the persistant data layer

Comment: @YassineBenHamida That's where I think differently. I'm seeing the frontend completely decoupled from the backend, each with its own presentation, business and data tiers. The exposed API of the backend is the presentation tier in my case, and the business tier is both the Angular services and the backend services.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is an SPA, a single-page-application. It contains everything, Model (changing of business data), View (templates with HTML) and Controller (your click- and other event-handlers in your components).

The Spring backend is an extension of the Model, for performing further data transformation and storing it on a database.

The Model-View-Something (there is also MVVM and derivations) is a pattern that comes from desktop-applications, but it doesn't really fit in the world of SPAs. And the Controller in MVC is often seen as redundant even in desktop-applications (because it just delegates stuff and not taking as big role as View and Model).

Important for you to know when you work with Angular is rather the Component-pattern. It is valid in Angular, in React, Vue and even in Vaadin. A component is chunk of both HTML and script-code manipulating that HTML. And components can nest each other allowing a hierarchical architecture.

Comment: I hope somebody comments on this, I want to know what others think.

Comment: I don't think, that "Spring is an extension of the Model", it's quite the contrary. The model (or parts of it) may be present in Angular, too, as it aggregates and transforms the data to suit the user's need or the requirements of the UI/UX. But the complete model with all its business logic and validation, is found in the backend, at least in any serious application. So, eventually Angular might contain an extension of the Model, and not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same project with angular as a frontend and spring boot as a backend, and i am still a little bit confused  about it's architecture just like you, but i finally had to adopt the MVC model since i am actually using controllers, defining models and rendering views (the json results).

Obviously your front end uses a CBA (component based architecture and your backend is using an MVC pattern since spring MVC is embedded inside spring boot so it actually uses the same logic.
here's a brief image of how spring boot dispatches between controllers and handles requests, you can consider your dispatcher servlet as the middleware between your front end and your backend (but keep in mind that it is embedded inside the spring boot container)
[image]